# How to make a selectable items menu with js and output value each item

Tags: php, jquery, html, select

I have seen other questions about the same thing but they are not what i am looking for i am wanting it to show the item and the price and show up the value on the page

I have some site code that output(show) items in my steam backpack and i wanted to  have it to be able to select items then output value which is the buy/sell price of each item. Below is the code for the selectable item(s) i use php i will just put it on without the php (1 single item). I do not want a selector dropdown i want the selector to be the item(s) clicked in the form below

I know i Use  the a code like the one below but i am not sure how i would implement it and it work correctly I want it to output and add at the Selected Price text so should be like Selected Price: value without having to press the trade/submit button.

```
<select name=""> 
<option value=""></option> 
<option value=""></option>
</select>
```

I have Provided all info i could think of if any other info is needed please let know
Here is the html of my php file i use

```
    <div class="container">
  <input style="float:right" value="76561198076819824" type="text" hidden="">
  <br>
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <div class="card" style="font-size: 200%;" id="rcorners1">
    <div class="card-group">
    <div class="card-body" style="color:black"><p align="left"><a href="../Craft_Hats"><span style="color:blue">Craft Hats Banking</span></a>&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-greater-than" style="font-size:20px"></i><i class="fas fa-greater-than" style="font-size:20px"></i> Buy</p>
    <div class="card-group">
    <div class="card-body bg-dark" id="rcorners2">
    <div class="stitched bg-dark"><div align="left">Selected Price:<input style="float:right" value="Trade" type="submit"></div></div>
    <div class="card-columns">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="backpack/style.css">
<label class="image-checkbox">
<div class="card  Unusual">

  <img src="http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/fWFc82js0fmoRAP-qOIPu5THSWqfSmTELLqcUywGkijVjZULUrsm1j-9xgEYYggGXxTjqjx8gMnyMv6NGucF1YNk4cgHiWNqxVUpZLflNGY_dAGSA_laWqw4o1u6XnZh65Y1VYa0puhIOVK4cLUhzmI" alt="item" style="width:100px" class=" Unusual  30767" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Unusual Airdog">
  <input name="image[]" value="" type="checkbox">
      <i class="fa fa-check" hidden=""></i>
  <div class="container Vintage">
    <p>100.00</p> 
  </div>
</div>
</label>


    <label class="image-checkbox">
<div class="card">

  <img src="http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/fWFc82js0fmoRAP-qOIPu5THSWqfSmTELLqcUywGkijVjZULUrsm1j-9xgEIUxQZUhz3tgdIidznA_OzBOESnN97sJEHiDI6xFIvY7HlMTMwIlXDUPBbWvA_8lq9CyY3uZUyA4fvp-sCcRKv6tUa3lr7Jg" alt="item" style="width:100px" class=" Unique  357" data-toggle="tooltip" title="The Half-Zatoichi">
  <input name="image[]" value="" type="checkbox">
      <i class="fa fa-check" hidden=""></i>
  <div class="Vintage">
    <p>1.00</p> 
  </div>
</div>
</label>



    </div>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </div>

        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Here is the styles this should be all that i used in this other than bootstrap 4 
      
     
     
    /*image gallery*/
    .image-checkbox {
        cursor: pointer;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 4px solid transparent;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        outline: 0;
    }
    input[type="checkbox"] {
        display: none;
    }

```
.image-checkbox-checked {
    border-color: #4783B0;
}
.image-checkbox .fa {
  position: absolute;
  color: #4A79A3;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.image-checkbox-checked .fa {
  display: block !important;
}
```

The Js i am using is here

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>

// image gallery
// init the state from the input
$(".image-checkbox").each(function () {
if ($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').first().attr("checked")) {
$(this).addClass('image-checkbox-checked');
}
else {
 $(this).removeClass('image-checkbox-checked');
   }
});

// sync the state to the input
$(".image-checkbox").on("click", function (e) {
$(this).toggleClass('image-checkbox-checked');
var $checkbox = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
$checkbox.prop("checked",!$checkbox.prop("checked"))

e.preventDefault();
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

so I would suggest putting the value in the value field of the checkbox. currently you have it set to nothing.  then just do an on click event for your check boxes.  get the checked ones using jquery checked. then just use the reduce function to sum up all the values.

run the snippet below for an example

```js
$('input:checkbox').click(function() {
  $('#span').html($('input:checkbox:checked').toArray().reduce(function(sum, element) {
    return sum + Number(element.value);
  }, 0));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" value="100"> 100
</p>
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" value="50"> 50
</p>
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" value="25"> 25
</p>
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" value="10"> 10
</p>


total: <span id="span">0</span>
```

Comment: That is what i needed 1 thing is my code only triggers a a css trigger to fire some style but not actually trigger the checkbox itself how can i fix that with the toggle?

Comment: Looks like you have sync state to input where you check the checbox. Cant you run the reduce $unc

Comment: Function in there?

Comment: this is the code   $(".image-checkbox").on("click", function (e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('image-checkbox-checked');
  var $checkbox = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
  $checkbox.prop("checked",!$checkbox.prop("checked"))

  e.preventDefault();
});

Comment: I do but it does not sync